# django query for list with join

Tags: django

In django I have to models A and B, B has FK reference to A.
A2B is one-to-many

In my controller code I select list of A according some criteria and this list is transferred to a template to generate html page.

This template uses FOR to generate list: {% for a in list_of_a %}

The question is that with every "a" printed I have to print related Bs as well. With non django code it would be simple join.
But how can I implement this in django?

thanks

Comment: `{% for b in a.b_set.all %} {{ b }} {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague, but the gist of it seems to be that you want to avoid the 1*N queries generated when looping through your `A`s.

In Django 1.4, you can use the new [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), which will still generate an extra query, but just one instead of 1*N.

Previous versions of Django have nothing similar, but there's an app called [django-batch-select](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select) that can be used to gain roughly equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this yourself, if you know how to work the inner magics of QuerySet. For example, see

https://github.com/benjiec/curious/blob/master/curious/graph.py

See the test case on how to use the traverse function

https://github.com/benjiec/curious/blob/master/tests/curious_tests/test_graph_fk.py